# Not getting an open Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to get a cursor from an SQLiteDatabase rawQuery but keep getting an `java.lang.IllegalStateException`. This exception to be precise:

```
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{frisbeergolf.gui/frisbeergolf.gui.Hole}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to acquire a reference on a close SQLiteClosable
```

(full log enclosed below)

This is my method inside a SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
    public int[] getAllPlayersInGame(Game game){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int count = this.getNumberOfPlayersInGame(game);
    int[] playerIDs = new int[count];

    Boolean b = db.isOpen();

    Cursor cursor = null;
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT playerID FROM " + gamesTable + " WHERE gameID = " + game.getGameId(), null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        playerIDs[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return playerIDs;
}
```

I made the boolean to check wheather the database is open or not. And it returns false.

**Can anyone help me se why?**

Full errorlog:

```
    02-05 19:30:25.080: W/dalvikvm(338): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught      exception (group=0x4001b188)
    02-05 19:30:25.080: E/AndroidRuntime(338): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{frisbeergolf.gui/frisbeergolf.gui.Hole}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to acquire a reference on a close SQLiteClosable
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to acquire a reference on a close SQLiteClosable
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:31)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:56)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1221)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1194)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at frisbeergolf.database.DBHandler.getAllPlayersInGame(DBHandler.java:175)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at frisbeergolf.database.DBHandler.getProgressAtHole(DBHandler.java:226)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at frisbeergolf.game.Game.getProgressAtHole(Game.java:63)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at frisbeergolf.gui.Hole.onCreate(Hole.java:31)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
    02-05 19:30:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: `at frisbeergolf.database.DBHandler.getAllPlayersInGame(DBHandler.java:175)`  To be certain, which is line 175?

Comment: I feel kind of stupid as I found the answer myself and its quite simple. I call and **close** a database in my getNumberOfPlayersInGame method. All I need to solve it was to swich order for these lines `int count = this.getNumberOfPlayersInGame(game); SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();`

Comment: You should post this as an answer for future visitors, glad you made it work!

Comment: Thanks for advice! As it is my first question I just looked through meta to find what is good practice in this situation. Answer will follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my own fault all the time.

I called, and **closed** a database in my `this.getNumberOfPlayersInGame(game);` method. Hence also closing the newly opened one.

The solution was just to switch these lines to this order and all worked just fine

```
    int count = this.getNumberOfPlayersInGame(game);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you posted the code, I would be able to give an example using your code, but I will use some of my own and hopefully we can resolve your issue.

https://bitbucket.org/XatikGroup/droiddraw/src/8aee6ffc4a7d089714c5003e32f29652eafd79ef/DroidDrawClient/src/com/xatik/app/droiddraw/client/databases/CommandsDbAdapter.java?at=master

I'm not entirely sure what 'this' is when you call

```
this.getReadableDatabase();
```

If you take a look at my class, I have a private static class inside the DbAdapter. This class helps opening the database. **I'm thinking this is where the issues are coming from in your code.**

Within my activity where I need the data, I would create an object of CommandsDbAdapter and then call the open() function.

```
CommandsDbAdapter cmdDbAdapter = new cmdDbAdapter(this);
cmdDbAdapter.open();
List<Command> commands = cmdDbAdapter.fetchCommandsForScript(1);
cmdDbAdapter.close();
```

I'm assuming there is code issues with whatever class is extending the SQLiteOpenHelper.  Please paste the whole code, or try and analyze the code I posted to see what's different.